FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT: Error occuring while logging in with vercel deployment for NextJS project
I am working on a project using NextJS with app router and MongoDB Atlas which included authentication and i am using next auth for the same. The code is working completely okay for the local host but vercel deployement encounters this issue. I searched the documentation and it says that FUNCTION_INVOCATION_TIMEOUT is due to the function invocation takes longer than the allowed execution time. It suggests to use the Edge functions which i dont have any idea how to use. I dont know if there is any error in my code due to which this error may be coming. When run locally the authentication works totally fine. So any help would be to the great help.
This is my code for login page:
"use client";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { signIn } from "next-auth/react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import Link from "next/link";
import "./login.css";
import localFont from "next/font/local";

const poppins = localFont({ src: "./fonts/Poppins-Regular.woff2" });
export default function Login() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [pending, setPending] = useState("");
  const [error, setError] = useState("");

  const router = useRouter();

  const handleEmailChange = (e) => {
    setEmail(e.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (e) => {
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  };
  const handleSigninwithGoogle = async () => {
    await signIn("google", { callbackUrl: "http://localhost:3000/admin" });
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (password === "" || email === "") {
      setError("Please fill the email and password");
      return;
    }
    try {
      setPending(true);
      const res = await signIn("credentials", {
        email,
        password,
        redirect: false,
      });

      if (res.error) {
        setError("invalid credentials");
        setPending(false);
        return;
      }

      router.push("/admin");
    } catch (error) {
      setPending(false);
      console.log(error.message);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="w-fit">
        <Link href="/">
          <img
            className="m-5 w-[200px] min-w-[200px]"
            src="/logo-full.png"
            alt="BlinkLink"
          />
        </Link>
      </div>
      <section
        className={`bg-[#4c956c] h-[645px] lg:mx-20 mx-10 shadow-xl flex rounded-2xl ${poppins.className}`}
      >
        {/* <div className="w-1/2 h-full lg:visible collapse rounded-l-2xl "></div> */}

        <div className="lg:w-1/2 w-full h-full bg-white lg:rounded-r-[50px] rounded-2xl flex flex-col items-center place-content-center">
          <form
            method="post"
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            className=" w-full h-fit flex flex-col items-center place-content-center"
          >
            <p className="text-4xl font-bold">Welcome Back</p>
            <p className="text-sm mb-2 mt-1">Log in your account</p>
            <div className="form-control h-12 mt-4 mb-2 relative w-2/3">
              <input
                type="text"
                name="email"
                value={email}
                onChange={handleEmailChange}
                className="bg-neutral-200 rounded-2xl h-full w-full border-none outline-none focus:outline-lime-400 px-0 py-5 text-sm"
              />
              <label className="absolute left-5 top-1/2 translate-y-[-55%] text-[0.85rem] pointer-events-none transition-all duration-100 ease-in">
                Email
              </label>
            </div>
            <div className="form-control h-12 my-2 relative w-2/3">
              <input
                type="password"
                name="password"
                value={password}
                onChange={handlePasswordChange}
                className="bg-neutral-200 rounded-2xl h-full w-full border-none outline-none focus:outline-lime-400 px-0 py-5 text-sm"
              />
              <label className=" absolute left-5 top-1/2 translate-y-[-55%] text-[0.85rem] pointer-events-none transition-all duration-100 ease-in">
                Password
              </label>
            </div>
            {error && <span className="text-sm text-red-500">{error}</span>}
            <button
              disabled={pending ? true : false}
              className="bg-purple-600 w-2/3 h-12 my-4 rounded-3xl text-[0.95rem] hover:ease-in hover:duration-200 hover:bg-purple-700 text-white disabled:bg-neutral-300"
              type="submit"
            >
              {pending ? "Logging in" : "Log in"}
            </button>
          </form>
          <p className="text-xs">
            Don&apos;t have an account?{" "}
            <span>
              <Link
                href="/signup"
                className=" text-[#4c956c] text-bold underline"
              >
                SignUp
              </Link>
            </span>
          </p>

          <p className="my-4 text-neutral-600">OR</p>
          <button
            onClick={handleSigninwithGoogle}
            className="bg-white border border-neutral-200 hover:bg-neutral-200 hover:ease-in hover:duration-200 flex items-center  place-content-center w-2/3 h-12 rounded-3xl text-[0.95rem]"
          >
            <img src="/google.png" className="w-6 mr-3" />
            <p>Log in with Google</p>
          </button>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

This is the route.js file code located in api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js:
import UserModel from "../../../../../models/UserModel";
import connectDb from "../../../../../utils/connectDB";
import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcryptjs";
import { signIn, signOut } from "next-auth/react";
import GoogleProvider from "next-auth/providers/google";

async function login(credentials) {
  try {
    await connectDb();
    const user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: credentials.email });
    const isCorrect = await bcrypt.compare(credentials.password, user.password);

    if (!isCorrect) throw new Error("wrong credentials");
    return user;
  } catch (er) {
    throw new Error("failed to login");
  }
}

async function createUserIfNotExists(token) {
  await connectDb();

  let user = await UserModel.findOne({ email: token.email });

  if (!user) {
    user = await new UserModel({
      email: token.email,
      name: token.name,
      image: token.picture,
    }).save();
  }
  if (user) {
    token.name = user.name;
  }

  // return user;
}

export const authOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
    signOut: "/admin",
  },
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials) {
        try {
          const user = await login(credentials);
          console.log("this is user = ", user);
          return user;
        } catch (errors) {
          console.log("fail to login = ", errors.message);
          throw new Error("failed to login");
        }
      },
    }),

    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
      httpOptions: {
        timeout: 100000,
      },
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      if (user) {
        token.id = user._id;
        token.email = user.email;
        console.log(user);
        await createUserIfNotExists(token);
        console.log("this is token", token);
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
        session.email = token.email;
        session.name = token.name;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
};
const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as GET, handler as POST };

I have also tried changing the locations for functions execution in vercel deployment. Both the location for deployment and database are now mumbai. So that should not be the issue. I really need a solution for this as this is my Full Stack Web Development course's assignment for this sem and i need to submit this ASAP.
Error log in vercel:
error-image
error-image-2
